# Color in TableForm

Tags: list-manipulation, style

Happy Easter!

How can I change the background color of one specific row in `TableForm`?
Or can I even do it ?

for instance:

```
TableForm[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"r1", "r2", "r3"}, {"c1", "c2"}}]
```

How can I make the background color of `r2` to be orange ?

Thanks!

Comment: `TableForm[{{a, b}, Item[#, Background -> Red] & /@ {c, d}, {e, f}}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"r1", "r2", "r3"}, {"c1", "c2"}}]`?

Comment: @kglr thank you very much. This works. However, I have a very long list and It would be tedious to replace every single second row item with your code. Is there also another way ?

Comment: You can do something like: `list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
list2 = MapAt[Item[#, Background -> Red] &, list, {{2, All}}];
TableForm[list2, TableHeadings -> {{"r1", "r2", "r3"}, {"c1", "c2"}}]` or like `list3 = list; list3[[2]] = Item[#, Background -> Red] & /@ list3[[2]];
TableForm[list3, TableHeadings -> {{"r1", "r2", "r3"}, {"c1", "c2"}}]`

Comment: @kglr that works ! Thank you very much. Can you please add it as answer, such that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}; 
list2 = MapAt[Item[#, Background -> Red] &, list, {{2, All}}]; 
TableForm[list2, TableHeadings -> {{"r1", "r2", "r3"}, {"c1", "c2"}}]
```

or

```
list3 = list; 
list3[[2]] = Item[#, Background -> Red] & /@ list3[[2]]; 
TableForm[list3, TableHeadings -> {{"r1", "r2", "r3"}, {"c1", "c2"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oddly, formatting provided by `Item` is ignored when it is in the `TableHeadings` values.